# C# GMap: How to draw a 120 degree beam angle on a map

Tags: c#, api, maps

how can I add a polygon to the map as in the picture below? From a certain point of coordinates should open a polygon long, for example, 1 kilometer and a 120-degree opening angle.

https://i.ibb.co/ZLKgvJs/image.png

```
private void CreateCircle(Double lat, Double lon, double radius, int ColorIndex)
    {
        GMapOverlay markers = new GMapOverlay(mygmap, "markers");
        PointLatLng point = new PointLatLng(lat, lon);
        int segments = 1080;

        List<PointLatLng> gpollist = new List<PointLatLng>();

        for (int i = 0; i < segments; i++)
        {
            gpollist.Add(FindPointAtDistanceFrom(point, i * (Math.PI / 180), radius / 1000));
        }

        GMapPolygon polygon = new GMapPolygon(gpollist, "Circle");
        switch (ColorIndex)
        {

            case 1:
                polygon.Fill = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(80, Color.Red));
                break;
            case 2:
                polygon.Fill = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(80, Color.Orange));
                break;
            case 3:
                polygon.Fill = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(20, Color.Aqua));
                break;
            default:
                MessageBox.Show("No search zone found!");
                break;
        }

        polygon.Stroke = new Pen(Color.Red, 1);
        markers.Polygons.Add(polygon);
        mygmap.Overlays.Add(markers);
    }


    public static GMap.NET.PointLatLng FindPointAtDistanceFrom(GMap.NET.PointLatLng startPoint, double initialBearingRadians, double distanceKilometres)
    {
        const double radiusEarthKilometres = 6371.01;
        var distRatio = distanceKilometres / radiusEarthKilometres;
        var distRatioSine = Math.Sin(distRatio);
        var distRatioCosine = Math.Cos(distRatio);

        var startLatRad = DegreesToRadians(startPoint.Lat);
        var startLonRad = DegreesToRadians(startPoint.Lng);

        var startLatCos = Math.Cos(startLatRad);
        var startLatSin = Math.Sin(startLatRad);

        var endLatRads = Math.Asin((startLatSin * distRatioCosine) + (startLatCos * distRatioSine * Math.Cos(initialBearingRadians)));
        var endLonRads = startLonRad + Math.Atan2(Math.Sin(initialBearingRadians) * distRatioSine * startLatCos, distRatioCosine - startLatSin * Math.Sin(endLatRads));

        return new GMap.NET.PointLatLng(RadiansToDegrees(endLatRads), RadiansToDegrees(endLonRads));
    }

    public static double DegreesToRadians(double degrees)
    {
        const double degToRadFactor = Math.PI / 180;
        return degrees * degToRadFactor;
    }

    public static double RadiansToDegrees(double radians)
    {
        const double radToDegFactor = 180 / Math.PI;
        return radians * radToDegFactor;
    }
```

My code can only draw a circle. Can it be changed so that it can draw a polygon from a certain point of coordinates with an indication of the direction, distance of drawing and the angle of aperture?

Answer (score 0):

Try to break your circle into 20,30,40 or 50 points, display only the points you want and draw a polyline for each 2 points

```
int n = 20; //number of points
for(i = 0; i<n ;i++)
{
    angle = i * (360/n);
    point.x = x_center + r * cos(angle);
    point.y = y_center + r * sin(angle);
}
```